# Python socket programming with multiple servers and one client

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following situation: 4 Unix devices and 1 PC that are all able to run python. 4 Unix devices are connected to an Ethernet switch, and then the Ethernet switch connects to the PC. The PC is acting as a "client" and 4 other devices are acting as "server", since the PC initializes the communication. This communication is bidirectional though, because 4 devices will process client's data and then send result signal back.

In Python, I declared 4 sockets using the same "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)" statement. The data then are sent over by 4 "socket.send" command. Immediately after above "send" commands I have "socket.recv" to get the data that are processed by all FPGAs.

The problem here is that I have no problem running a single PC to FPGA connection. However, when I tried to increase the number of devices to 2, the data rate becomes extremely slow.

Is above the right way for me to establish one client and 4 servers system? 
Thanks!

Comment: So you have 4 recv successively? Did you check whether one of your device is extremely slow to respond?

Comment: There was no problem when communicating with one single device. Current implementation is calling 4 recv successively. May I know if there is any way to improve this?